# How to truncate UILabel with sizeToFit enabled?

Tags: ios, swift, uilabel

How can I get this label to truncate with ellipsis while retaining its `sizeToFit` attribute? In effect, I want the label to size itself based on its content while having a maximum width. The label is contained in a `UIView` with `clipsToBounds` enabled.

```
label.text = labelText
label.sizeToFit()
label.frame.origin.y = 16
label.frame.origin.x = 16
label.lineBreakMode = .byTruncatingTail
label.numberOfLines = 1
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand what you want, after calling `sizeToFit`, set the label's width to whatever maximum width you want.

```
label.text = labelText
label.lineBreakMode = .byTruncatingTail
label.numberOfLines = 1
label.sizeToFit()
label.frame.origin.y = 16
label.frame.origin.x = 16
if label.frame.width > someMaximumWidth {
    label.frame.size.width = someMaximumWidth
}
```